# Integrating Fortran code in Julia

Tags: fortran, julia

I am using the GNU gfortran compiler (on Cygwin) for my own module. A good example will hopefully start from the compilation stage, address mangled names and call the subroutine from Julia via `ccall`. Most examples I've seen skip the first two stages.

So imagine that I have the following module in Fortran 90 file named 'f90tojl.f90':

```
module m
contains
    integer function five()
      five = 5
    end function five
end module m
```

This example is from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#Name_mangling_in_Fortran). I compile it with gfortran as follows to create a shared library:

```
gfortran -shared -O2 f90tojl.f90 -o -fPIC f90tojl.so
```

And my, admittedly shaky, understanding from reading the Julia docs suggest that I should be able to call the function five like so:

```
ccall( (:__m_MOD_five, "f90tojl"), Int, () )
```

It didn't work for me. I get `'error compiling anonymous: could not load module f90tojl...`. Anyone cares to enlighten me? I got the sneaky sense I'm doing something silly....

In the official [doc](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/calling-c-and-fortran-code/), the emphasis is on C. I'm also aware of [this](https://github.com/Keno/Cxx.jl) for C++. In R and Python, the momentum -- I have Cython and Rcpp in mind -- seems to be C/C++. Similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3148763/1965432), I want to get a sense of how easy it is to interface Julia with Fortran vs Julia with C/C++.

Comment: It does depend on which platform/fortran compiler you are using.  Interfacing to Fortran varies depending on vendor.

Comment: Your C++ link is from the extremely out-of-date Julia 0.1, and the current work on C++ interop is in [Cxx.jl](https://github.com/Keno/Cxx.jl)

Comment: The OP's post on (julia-users) can be found [here](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/julia-users/zMtEggnGUAM/discussion).

Comment: Change `"f90tojl"` to `"f90tojl.so"` works for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Calling Fortran and C are essentially the same, as the documentation says. There are just far fewer examples because there is far less code people want to wrap, I suppose. Wrapping C is super easy in Julia, very pleasant. Its not typically done for speeding up Julia, like with R or Python, but more to take advantage of quality code already written.

Julia's standard library itself is a great example of integrating with Fortran code, e.g. here is the [Julia wrapper](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/linalg/arpack.jl) for [ARPARK](https://github.com/opencollab/arpack-ng). Outside of `Base`, [glmnet](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v33/i01/) is written in Fortran, and there is a [Julia wrapper for it (GLMNet.jl)](https://github.com/simonster/GLMNet.jl).

I don't see how the modern Fortran distinction matters.

Comment: Now you've changed your question quite substantially. I think you should post it on the julia-users mailing list. This type of question is off-topic for SO, as it falls under: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."

Comment: I'd just leave it now.

Comment: Posted it on julia-users. And tried to make the question more concrete.

Answer (score 5):

For those who, like me, got here with the hope of a copy-paste recipe to get the hands over the matter, here is a working code (typos-corrected from http://julia-programming-language.2336112.n4.nabble.com/example-for-ccall-use-and-fortran-tp7737p7740.html).

Fortran file: simplemodule.f95

```
module simpleModule

contains
function foo(x)
  integer :: foo, x
  foo = x * 2
end function foo


end module simplemodule
```

Which has to be compiled with 
`gfortran simplemodule.f95 -o simplemodule.so -shared -fPIC`, producing the `simplemodule.so` shared library file.

Then, in Julia,

```
a = Int32[3]
ccall((:__simplemodule_MOD_foo, "./simplemodule.so"), Int32, (Ptr{Int32},), a)
```

returns `6`.

The [thread](http://julia-programming-language.2336112.n4.nabble.com/example-for-ccall-use-and-fortran-tp7737.html) contains other examples, too.

Comment: I had to add the flag `-ffree-form` to the compile/link line `gfortran`.

Comment: And for the Intel oneAPI  `ifort` or `ifx` compiler ( after adding a line 
`!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT, ALIAS:'foo' :: foo`
above `function foo(x)`
the ccall looks like this:
`ccall((:foo, "simpleModule.dll"), Int32, (Ptr{Int32},), a)`, 
where the dll got compiled in Windows by 
`ifx -dll simpleModule.f90`