# Compiling Fortran77 with Julia

Tags: fortran, julia, fortran77

I have a bunch of Fortran77 code that I need to use for my research but I'm having trouble compiling it to run on my MacBook so I turned to Julia.  I'm new to the language but for the life of me I can't figure out how to execute a Fortran script directly in Julia.  All I want is to have a program that runs a F77 script and hands control directly to Fortran.  I would just rewrite it with Julia or Numpy but there's about 10,000 lines of code and less than 200 lines of comment and I don't have time for that.

Comment: It needs to be compiled before julia can call it.
use `ccall` see [docs](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/calling-c-and-fortran-code/) do ctrl+f for fortran to get the fortran specifics.

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27498755/examples-of-integrating-fortran-code-in-julia
and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28373693/calling-a-fortran-function-from-julia-returning-an-array-unknown-function-seg

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Examples of integrating Fortran code in Julia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27498755/examples-of-integrating-fortran-code-in-julia)

Comment: Fortran programs are not *scripts* they need to be compiled a compiler

Comment: IMO, this isn't a duplicate of "Examples of integrating Fortran code in Julia."  This question includes a misunderstanding that is nice to answer here.  Does it really need to be closed?

Comment: @MattB. fair point. I am retracting my close-vote

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems from the wording of your question like you want to use Julia to directly call Fortran "scripts" – presumably Fortran `.f` source files – is that accurate?

As others have indicated in the comments, Fortran is not a scripting language: you cannot directly execute Fortran source files; instead you must use a Fortran compiler (e.g. [gfortran](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Fortran), [ifort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Fortran_Compiler)) to translate Fortran programs into native libraries or executables for the system you want to run programs on. Julia will not help with this in any way as Julia is not a Fortran interpreter or compiler – it can neither run Fortran code directly nor convert Fortran source files into executables/libraries.

If, however, you already have a Fortran shared library compiled (`.so` file on Linux, `.dylib` on macOS, `.dll` on Windows), you can call it easily from Julia, as described in [Integrating Fortran code in Julia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27498755/integrating-fortran-code-in-julia). If you can compile Fortran source code to an executable (as opposed to a shared library), then you do not need anything else to run it – executables, by definition, are standalone.

Most projects in compiled languages like Fortran or C/C++ come with [Makefiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makefile) or other mechanisms to help invoke a compiler to generate the appropriate binary artifacts (executables and/or libraries).

Comment: Thanks, sorry about the confusion with the word script.  In physics we often use 'script' and 'program' interchangeably even though we shouldn't.  

You are correct.  I have a Fortran77 program that is a `.f` and I'm having trouble getting any of the common compilers to compile it.  I tried gfortran to no avail.  Technically I do have the executables but they were compiled for an old Sun workstation running on SunOS and I'm on a Mac.

Comment: Right. Those executables are definitely not going to work on a Mac and Julia can't help you compile Fortran. You can either keep trying figure out how to invoke gfortran to compile the code, or translate the code. 10k LOC is not as much as it seems – especially since it's not uncommon for code to shrink by a factor of 10x when going from verbose static languages to terse dynamic ones like Julia. Either way, good luck!

Comment: Yep, sorry.  I'm still new to stackexchange